# i need to stop sound on image button when back button pressed or home button pressed

Tags: android, android-studio, media-player, imagebutton, onbackpressed

in the image, I'm playing one sound on looping
total code is working fine but when I press the back button or home button on the image play sound didn't stop
please help me I'm new I'm making this app by my own

This is my code:

MY JAVA CODE:

```
ImageView imgPlay;
ImageView imgPause;
int sound1 = -1;
SoundPool soundPool;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);


    imgPlay = findViewById(R.id.imgPlay);
    imgPause = findViewById(R.id.imgPause);

    final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(play.this, R.raw.song1);


    this.soundPool = new SoundPool(2, 3, 0);
    this.sound1 = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1)

    imgPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sound.start();
            sound.setLooping(true);
        }
    });

    imgPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sound.pause();

        }
    });
    
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            play.this.soundPool.autoPause();
            play.this.soundPool.play(play.this.sound1, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        }
    });
   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onPause lifecycle of your activity and pause the  sound there.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sound.pause();
}
```